# port scanning tool in batch using paping.exe that scan all ports

Tags: batch-file, port

I have a port scanning tool and it uses a command line Program called paping.exe, (If you want it you can install it here, https://code.google.com/archive/p/paping/downloads) and so far i can make it scan a few ports on a ip or website but it would be too time consuming to make it manually scan all ports from 1-65,535 so i need it to scan all 65,535 ports and display which ports are open without taking a lot of time

Heres my code:

```
@echo off
::BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" 
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params = %*:"="
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> 
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
 pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
::--------------------------------------

:PortScan
set /p Ip=Enter a IP or Website to ping:
paping.exe %Ip% -p 1 -c 1

paping.exe %ip% -p %port% -c 1 | findstr "protocol=TCP"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
cls
color 0a
echo Port %port% is Open.
) else (
cls
color 4
echo Port is Closed.
)

pause
goto :LoopScan

:LoopScan
 @echo off
 setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
 set /a count = 1
 set /a count += 1
 paping.exe %ip% -p !count! -c 1 | findstr "protocol=TCP"
 if %errorlevel% == 0 (
 cls
 color 0a
 set /
 goto openport
 echo These ports are open: %%n
) else (
cls
color 4
goto closeport
echo Ports are Closed.
)
pause
)
endlocal
pause





openport:
Echo The Following Ports Are Open: !count!
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: execute `for /L %a in (1 1 20) do echo %a` from command prompt (in a batchfile use this syntax: `for /L %%a in (1 1 20) do echo %%a`). Seeing the result, you should be able to adapt and build it into your script.

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to increment a counter for the port number but why bother.  There are so many better console applications that allow you to enter in a port range.  `NMAP` is the best. Scan a range of ports: `nmap -p 1-100 192.168.1.1` Scan all ports: `nmap -p- 192.168.1.1`